EXIM4 How can I configure a smarthost server to forward just some specific recipients?
I'm using exim4 in ubuntu server, with a splitted file configuration.
This server works as a normal internet smtp server, but for some specific recipients addresses (es. regex rule) I need to forward the outbound messages to a SMTP relay server (smarthost) with authentication.
So when my exim4 server receive a message that matches a filter, it should not be sent to its mx domain server but to a custom smarthost that will provide the finaly delivery.
Is it possibile?
I found just how to set a smarthost for all messages, but not for some custom recipients.

The solution is to add these commmand:
   headers_remove = Received

at the end of remote_smtp transport in
/etc/exim4/conf.d/transport/30_exim4-config_remote_smtp

